# How a private key (Pem format) can be saved as One-line string

Tags: python, rsa, newline, private-key, pem

I save a private rsa key in pem format

```
(key=RSA.construct((n,e,d,p,q,u)) 
private_key = key.exportKey("PEM"))
```

but saving it in a Pem file with

```
saveFile.write(str(private_key)
```

it does not get saved as a one line string (because it contains '\n') and it causes me problems cause I need to read it afterwards as a one-line variable so I can compare it

Comment: The PEM format includes linebreaks so you have to be able to handle them. Please explain your comparing problem!

Comment: Afterwards I want to load the rsa like this in my program    

rsa = linecache.getline('PemArxeio.pem', 14).strip()
print ("rsa is :  ", rsa)

And there's also data before and after the rsa in my pem file. So my rsa  starts at line 14 but i dont know where it end. Also, I want to know at which line is the next value .Thats why I  need to save the entirety as one-line string

Comment: @KlausD. So can you help me how to handle linebreaks in the pem format??

Comment: This sounds like an [x y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please explain what problem you are actually trying to solve!

Comment: @KlausD. Well I want to save in a Pem file a private key (in pem format) and the p,q,d,n,u which are used in order to make this rsa key. Then I create another python project and i want to read the data from the pem file and save them in variables in order to use them to my new python project.  So I use this code to take the data from the pem file 
p0 = linecache.getline('PemArxeio.pem', 2).strip()
print ("p0 is :  ", p0)

q0 = linecache.getline('PemArxeio.pem', 4).strip()
print ("q0 is :  ", q0)

Comment: @KlausD. But when it gets to rsa key is more than one line in the pem file... thats why i want to convet it as a one-line string in order to be able to save it in a str variable like this 

rsa = linecache.getline('PemArxeio.pem', 14).strip()
print ("rsa is :  ", rsa)

Comment: Why don't you add you explanation to the question?